# Transitions between animations

Tags: animation, game-engine

Maybe this is a dumb question.

I have been animating a character doing several basic actions.
The main one I have a problem with is the running animation.
I've started each animation at the idle pose and he moves to run for a few steps then returns to idle.

The problem with this is obviously that it looks strange if every few steps he returns to standing. He should run for as long as possible.

So the question is, am I supposed to have a transition animation between idle and running, so that the run can go on indefinitely, or is there a way to loop a section of the run animation until he stops?

Comment: yes it would make sense to have: idle / acceleration / running / deceleration... this way, for example, you can make it run as long as you wish

Answer (score 1):

You can loop a section by using the **Action actuator** and setting the **start** and **end** frames to only those that are part of the running state. You can also use the "Blendin" options to blend between states.

You can do this for as many states as you want, though it would be *preferred* to have separate "actions" (in the action editor) for each state, such as running, idle, etc.